# Matlab - replacing all negative and positive values

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset with many channels and many trials (each corresponding to a separate .mat file or data array).

I want to replace all negative values with -1 and all positive values with + 1 for a single row (for i = 1:n (# of trials) replace all values positive values in (22,:) with +1 and all negative values with -1).

Hope that's clear.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want to replace all positive numbers with 1 and all negative with -1? or only for certain rows? What do you mean by (22,:)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If A is your matrix NxN.

Do

```
A(X,:) = sign(A(X,:));
```

Where X is the row you want to change.

Comment: True. But this case is not specified then I didn't talk about it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, all you need to do is this, assuming your input matrix is `A` and that you want to change the values in it's 22nd row:

```
A(22,(A(22,:)<0)) = -1;
A(22,(A(22,:)>0)) = 1;
```

For example:

```
>> A = randint(25,5,[-10,10]);
>> A(22,:)

ans =

   -10    -1    -5     1    10

>> A(22,(A(22,:)<0)) = -1;
>> A(22,(A(22,:)>0)) = 1;
>> A(22,:)

ans =

   -1    -1    -1     1    1
```